# Can't access sqlcmd using username password

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlcmd

I am new to SQL Server. Please help me to fix.

I have created a user with password in SQL Server Management Studio (2008 R2). When I use `sqlcmd` with this user, sqlcmd says

```
C:\Console2>sqlcmd -U admin
Password:
```

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Server machinename, Line 1
>   Login failed for user 'admin'.

I can access the server with this user using SQL Server Management Studio.

P.S

- I have two instance of SQL Server Management Studio (2008 R2 and 2012). I can access that user from both version of SQL Server Management Studio.
- Whenever I connect using `sqlcmd` and execute `select @@version` query, it always says 2012, even I am connecting 2008 R2's `sqlcmd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that you have multiple server instances on your computer. Some MS products install the SQL Server Developer edition unless you explicitly tell it not to. So, unless you are explicitly telling `sqlcmd` which instance to connect to, it may be connecting to something you aren't expecting.

```
sqlcmd -S servername -d database name -U id
```

Comment: Thanks.
sqlcmd -S mypc\sqlexpress -U admin -P admin is working fine.<br/>If I am trying to connect via jdbc, I it not working and it says `java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'admin'.` My JDBC connection string is `Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/test1;instance=mypc\\sqlexpress","admin","admin");`

Comment: We were also facing the same issue with newly created user in sqlcmd. We were able to use SQL Management Studio but use to get "login failed for user 'user1'" error in sqlcmd.  After some try and run methods, we figured out our password have some special characters which are not supported by cmd prompt and that's why we  use to get this error.
Solution: Use all values in double quotes (" ")
e.g. sqlcmd -S "server_name" -U "username" -P "password"

Comment: You need to escape special characters in the password. The $ character needs to be escaped with a backtick. Example: sqlcmd -S servername -d database name -U id -P "my`$Password"

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-S MyServer\MyInstance
```

and for the database as well

Answer (score 0):

By default login failed error message is nothing but a client user connection has been refused by the server due to mismatch of login credentials. First task you might check is to see whether that user has relevant privileges on that SQL Server instance and relevant database too, thats good. Obviously if the necessary prvileges are not been set then you need to fix that issue by granting relevant privileges for that user login.
[Check out this post, it shows how to trouble-shoot this error.](http://web.archive.org/web/20100212233235/http://sqlserver-qa.net/blogs/tools/archive/2007/05/18/msg-18456-level-14-state-1-server-servername-line-1-login-failed-for-user-name.aspx)

Comment: Thanks.
sqlcmd -S mypc\sqlexpress -U admin -P admin is working fine.

Comment: If I am trying to connect via jdbc, I it not working and it says `java.sql.SQLException: Login failed for user 'admin'.` My JDBC connection string is `Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/test1;instance=mypc\\sqlexpress","admin","admin");`

Comment: Above comments are belongs to dazedandconfused. @Rahul sorry comments are changed.